# Deploy asp.net website in IIS 7.5 locally

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, iis-7.5

I get this error when deploying website in 11s 7.5 :

```
Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error: 


Line 16:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
Line 17: 
Line 18:     <authentication mode="Forms">
Line 19:       <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
Line 20:     </authentication>
```

Source File: C:\Users*\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\web\web\web.config    Line: 18

I am trying to deploy my website locally for testing.

Comment: Please have a look at this document : **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a15ebt6c%28VS.80%29.aspx**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out with follwing solution:

1. Delete the bin and obj folders, run a Clean Solution and built it again, the error goes away.
2. check the Application Pool the site is running under to make sure the Application Pool is using the .NET 4.0 Framework (instead of .NET 2.0 Framework).

Comment: I don't have the bin and obj folder.

Comment: It was running on v4.0. I still get the same error. I have edited my post to show the source file.

Comment: I started afresh and this is the error I am getting now: Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Global" Language="C#" %>